# Changing feature value type in RapidMiner

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, rapidminer

I have a dataset with many attributes (2k) which a few of them (about 10) are not binary and the rest are binary (0,1) , I want to change the value types of these binary attributes from integer to binomial , as the name of features are not fixed I want to do it based on their values ! (i.e change the value types of all attributes with values of 0,1 from integer to binomial)

Is there any straight way of doing this in Rapid Miner ?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `Integer to binomial` operator? E.g, you can select the wanted attributes via the `numeric_value_filter` (one of the options within the operator).